# How to give a suggestion from the sphinx index?

Tags: sphinx, search-suggestion

I wonder if there is a way to give a suggestion from the sphinx index.

for instance,
  when I search 'sadfasasas' on google, I get 6 results.
          and it said.' Do you mean "sasasasas".
  when I search by 'sasasasas', I get 289,000 results.

How should I do to implement this feature? (Let's say the two keywords are all right
spelling. and I want to give the suggestion 'sasasasas' just because it's seems like
'sadfasasas', and it can find many results by sphinx ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are script, config, readme in sphinx/misc/suggest folder. You could try suggestion service out of the box.

Comment: I tried this, and it gives me totally irrelevant results. Maybe I need to configure my initial index in a way...